# Apache Cordova : Office 365 API SharePointClient | How To download one drive files?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I am able to list all the files that i have for my one drive account but need to know how I could download them to my Android or Windows mobile phone.

I tried using the weburl that I receive from the item but looks like it will need the token.

Current JavaScript code :

```
var AuthenticationContext = new O365Auth.Context();
var discoveryContext = new O365Discovery.Context(); // new DiscoveryServices.Context(new AuthenticationContext(authUrl), appId, redirectUrl);
discoveryContext.services(AuthenticationContext.getAccessTokenFn('Microsoft.SharePoint')).then(function (capabilities) {
    capabilities.forEach(function (v) {
        if (v.capability === 'MyFiles') {
            var msg = "";
            var sharePointnew = new Microsoft.CoreServices.SharePointClient(v.resourceId + '/_api/v1.0/me/',
                        AuthenticationContext.getAccessTokenFn(v.resourceId));

            Microsoft.FileServices.FileFetcher

            var elementInfo = document.getElementById('popup_body');
            document.getElementById('popup_header').innerHTML = "My One Drive Files";
            /* This should open a popup */
            document.getElementById('popup_div').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('popup_overlay').style.display = "block";
            elementInfo.innerHTML += 'One Drive Files:';



            var fileName = 'demo.txt';

            var store = cordova.file.dataDirectory;

            var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer(); 
                console.log("About to start transfer"); 


           sharePointnew.files.getItems().fetch().then(function (result) {
                msg = '';
                result.currentPage.forEach(function (item) {

                    elementInfo.innerHTML += "<br />" + item.name + "<br />";
                    fileTransfer.download(item.webUrl, store + fileName,
                    function (entry) {
                        console.log("Success!");

                    },
                        function (err) {
                            console.log("Error");
                            console.dir(err);
                        });

                    msg += item._odataType + ' "' + item.name + '"\n';
                    var s = "";
                });                   



                console.log('All file system items: \n' + msg);
            }, function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you're still running into this issue - can you share the error message that appears when you're running this code?